# manipulating date object with javascript

Tags: javascript, date

i have been tinkering with the date object.

I want to add a dynamic amount of days to a day and then get the resulting date as a variable and post it to a form.

```
var startDate = $('#StartDate').datepicker("getDate");
    var change = $('#numnights').val();
    alert(change);
    var endDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(),startDate.getDate() + change);
```

does everything correctly except the last part. it doesnt add the days onto the day

```
take this scenario:
startdate = 2011-03-01   
change = 1  
alert change = 1
endDate = 2011-03-11 *it should be 2011-03-02*
```

thank you to all the quick replies.

converting change variable to an integer did the trick. thank you.

```
parseInt(change)
```

just to extend on this: is there a way to assign a variable a type, such as var charge(int)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have fallen victim to string concatenation.

Try changing your last parameter in the Date constructor to: `startDate.getDate() + parseInt(change)`

See [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_variables) for future reference.

Comment: changing the variable to an integer worked. however, if the day goes into a new month the month stays the same.

Comment: It shouldn't.  For example, if you called `var dt = new Date(2010, 11, 32);` your dt object will contain January 1, 2011. The Date constructor handles overflow of months and days. I can set up an example for you to see if you like.

Comment: Hopefully this example helps clear things up for you: http://www.webdevout.net/test?01d

Comment: // NOTE: Months are indexed from 0. So 0 = January and 11 = December
this examples a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

convert `change` to a number before adding it. it looks like you're getting a string concatenation operation rather than the addition you're expectingin your code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are concatenating instead of using the mathematical operator. Try this instead,

```
var endDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(),startDate.getDate() + (+change));
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not adding the ending day, you are concatinating it so `'1' + '1' = '11'`

use `parseInt()` to make sure you are working with integers

example

```
var change = parseInt($('selector').val());
```

Also, with this solution, you could easily end up with a day out of range if you are say on a start date of the 29th of the month and get a change of `5`